# What's the correct practice to add common properties to multiple classes?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, subclassing

Suppose I have one table view controller (controlling a static table view) and another regular view controller.

I want to add a common property to both of them. The first thing came in my mind is subclassing, meaning let these two controllers derive from a common abstract super class. After pondering a bit, I recall protocol can also achieve this.

My questions is, which approach will be the correct practice, or there are better practices?

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing is likely the correct approach.  Protocols don't add properties automatically, they only dictate that if your class conforms to a specific one that the class implements them.  If your coming from the Java world then an interface would be the equivalent.

A category might be appropriate if you want to add common functionality (methods) to all instance of a class, such as a UITableview controller.  The downside is that you can't declare additional instance variables (or properties) via a category (well technically you can via associated objects, but that's another rabbit hole).